# Transfering multiple files and meta data in POST request

Tags: rest, post, networking, microservices, transfer

I've got a Python Django Backend running, and want to design a microservice. This microservices has a rest POST endpoint open. Now I want to transfer multiple binary files and some meta data (as json?) in a single POST request from Django to the microservice. What would be the besteht way to accomplish this.
I thought about transfering the data as multipart, but I think it's Mord for HTML forms. Also thought about protobuf. Would appreciate if you could help me, what's the most common way for such problems? What's the most efficient way?
It shouldn't be important, that I am using Django or Python for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use `multipart/form-data`. This is supported (as in builin) by all web application servers and almost web clients. It supports multiple arbitrary binary files and other data in the same request.

So my answer is [KISS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

*P.S. It is not only for forms.*